# Installing Gunicorn using Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, cygwin

How can I install [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)?

I can't seem to find the Gunicorn Package on Cygwin...Unless I'm understanding the [issue](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/407) on github wrong, I think it does support Gunicorn.

Also I found this in the [changelog](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/news.html#id5):

> ## 0.17.2 / 2013-01-07
>
> - optimize readline
> - make imports errors more visiblle when loading an app or a logging class
> - fix tornado worker: don’t pass ssl options if there are none
> - fix PEP3333: accept only bytetrings in the response body
> - fix support on CYGWIN platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can recall it is a unix only application, but plans are in the works to make it work on cygwin. Don't think this has come to pass yet.

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/407

Comment: How do you explain the gunicorn change log then? It states that there is a fix: `fix: support on Cygwin platforms`.

Comment: I suspect if this was functional on Cygwin there would be documentation either on their website or on github. Just because something appears in the changelog doesn't mean it was either fully implemented at the time or still exists now.

No change logs for nearly 9 months probably suggest the latter. If you do find anything then do let us know

Comment: @Renier: Here, https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524, benoitc states that it is coming with release R20.